# WPF: Properties with ReadOnly attribute not being XAML serialized

Tags: xaml, serialization, readonly, xamlwriter

I'm working on a C# WPF application that makes use of a Windows Forms PropertyGrid to allow the user to view and change an object's properties.  Some properties I want to be visible but locked, so I'm setting their ReadOnly attribute to true.

However, elsewhere in the project we're using the XAML serializer to serialize objects and have found that the properties with the ReadOnly attribute set are being omitted from the serialization.

To demonstrate this:

```
// Simple class containing 3 properties, one of which has a ReadOnly attribute
public class TestClass
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public int b { get; set; }
    public int c { get; set; }
}
```

Running this code:

```
TestClass test = new TestClass();

test.a = 1;
test.b = 2;
test.c = 3;

string xStr = XamlWriter.Save(test);

Console.WriteLine(xStr);
```

gives the output:

```
<TestClass a="1" c="3" xmlns="clr-namespace:myTest;assembly=myTest" />
```

Clearly the 'b' property is missing.

Is this correct behaviour?  Is it possible to serialize properties that have ReadOnly set to true?

Comment: Perhaps the properties are omitted because it would not be possible to `Deserialise` them

Comment: Perhaps.  I had anticipated/hoped that the ReadOnly attribute would only affect the PropertyGrid display; the "read only" properties have both get and set methods so are intended to be read/write.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy that your output may not be deserializable then you can achieve what you want by also decorating your `[ReadOnly(true)]` property with:

```
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
```